# SQL SELECT ... WHERE... IN; Any thoughts on getting duplicated values (or a workaround)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, where-in

I have a question about SQL, in my Python program, i have a list called 'snum' with 900 items containing numbers, some of them are duplicated in the list.

The issue is that at executing the next SQL statement:

```
db.execute("SELECT id FROM numbers WHERE num IN ({0})".format(', '.join('?' for _in tuple(snum))), tuple(snum))
```

The returning data contains 414 elements(non duplicated id's).

I need an statement that returns 900 id's, even if they are duplicated.

Can't find a solution. I'm pretty new in the world of programming.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I'm using SQLite version 3.33.0

**Edit2**:

Current Workaround is to set a for loop with an sql statement inside:

```
list = []
for element in snum:
    db.execute("SELECT id FROM numbers WHERE num = ?", (element,))
    sel = db.fetchone()
    list.append(sel[0])
```

These code creates a list containig the id for every number of the original one (900 id's)

Still not sure if this is the best answer.

Comment: `.format` just begs for SQL injection and conversion problems. The query itself doesn't remove duplicates. If you get only 414 IDs, it's because only those exist in the table. The same `ID` appearing twice in the `IN` clause won't result in duplicate results.

Comment: That's the issue, IN clause doesn't returns duplicate results, so i need a workaround. Maybe i should create a 'for loop' with the SQL statement inside, returning one ID at a time, but i was hoping on finding a better solution than that.

In terms of SQL Injection, there's no user input on SQL statements, and the APP is made to work locally, so no chance for that to happen, Thanks for the advice.

Comment: From David Boland: *The id itself in your query will be returned as unique from your SQL. If you want to return 900 ids then you should try to find the column on the table you are querying that is not unique - there should be a primary key there somewhere?*

Comment: `IN` doesn't control how results are returned. SQL doesn't need loops. If you need the original data to be returned, it has to be included as *table data* in one way or another. How you do that depends on the database you use. Some support the use of [table value constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) while others may require inserting the values into a table variable or a temporary table. Once you have that data set, you can use an OUTER JOIN with the actual table

Comment: id is PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, num is UNIQUE

Comment: Which database and version are you using? It matters - while all current SQL Server version support `VALUES`, only MySQL 8.0.19 and later support it

Comment: sqlite3 version 3.33.0